# How to merge XML nodes with common subnodes while concatenating text of one differing subnode in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How to merge XML nodes with common subnodes while concatenating the text of one differing subnode in XSLT? I can use XSLT 1 or 2. I have basic XSLT knowledge but do not know where to start with this one.

This is the given XML:

```
<fields>
    <field>
        <dc-schema>dc</dc-schema>
        <dc-element>description</dc-element>
        <dc-qualifier>abstract</dc-qualifier>
        <type-bind>Audio</type-bind>
    </field>
    
    <field>
        <dc-schema>dc</dc-schema>
        <dc-element>description</dc-element>
        <dc-qualifier>abstract</dc-qualifier>
        <type-bind>Video</type-bind>
    </field>
    
    <field>
        <dc-schema>dc</dc-schema>
        <dc-element>description</dc-element>
        <dc-qualifier>sponsorship</dc-qualifier>
        <type-bind>Audio</type-bind>
    </field>
</fields>
```

This is the desired result:

```
<fields>
    <field>
        <dc-schema>dc</dc-schema>
        <dc-element>description</dc-element>
        <dc-qualifier>abstract</dc-qualifier>
        <type-bind>Audio, Video</type-bind>
    </field>
    
    <field>
        <dc-schema>dc</dc-schema>
        <dc-element>description</dc-element>
        <dc-qualifier>sponsorship</dc-qualifier>
        <type-bind>Audio</type-bind>
    </field>
</fields>
```

Comment: This seems to be a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: So you want to group `field` elements by the first three child elements, see [tag:xslt-grouping].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a grouping like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="fields/field" group-by="concat(dc-schema,dc-element,dc-qualifier)">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::type-bind)]"/>
        <type-bind><xsl:value-of select="current-group()/type-bind" separator=", "/></type-bind>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93F8dUv